# Specify new length for a line in LibreCad

Tags: dimensions

I created a line in LibreCad. The line is 1" long.
I would like to make this line 1.5" long.

How can I enter new length for this line?

Constraint - I know of the lengthen tool, but I do not want to do the measuring then math to figure out how long it needs to be.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right place to ask. Graphic design is not after all the same thing as industrial design or engineering. Drafting usually is not considered graphic design. So unless you can specify how this is related to graphic design i think this ought to be closed.

Comment: I guess you have already asked this in a technical drawing site and got redirected here due the unwillingness to make calculations. But it's enough if you can calculate that chaining a copy of your line at the end of the original makes a longer line than the wanted 1,5". So make a copy of your line and move it to the end of the original. It snaps if you have all point snaps ON except snap to grid. Then draw a Center&Radius circle R=1,5"  starting from the beginning of the original line. Finally drag the endpoint of the original line to the crossing of the circle and the 2nd line.